# Can we assign an id for the AWS X-ray segment, which going to be autogenerated by AWS for a subsegment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I send a segment with a subsegment to x-ray API. Subsegment is an s3 PutObject request. When X-ray receives this request, It automatically creates a segment for the s3 subsegment and assigns a random id.
Is this possible to assign an id (or get to know the id) before sending the request to x-ray API?

Here is the raw data of the segment.

```
{
    "Id": "1-620bae7d-daf2e1177923ffb30e4c9729",
    "Duration": 5.869,
    "LimitExceeded": false,
    "Segments": [
        {
            "Id": "f0125b56d62b456b",
            "Document": {
                "id": "f0125b56d62b456b",
                "name": "raw-xray-dev",
                "start_time": 1644932733.217,
                "trace_id": "1-620bae7d-daf2e1177923ffb30e4c9729",
                "end_time": 1644932733.511,
                "aws": {
                    "ecs": {
                        "container": "xxxxxx"
                    },
                    "xray": {
                        "package": "aws-xray-sdk",
                        "sdk_version": "3.3.4",
                        "sdk": "X-Ray for Node.js"
                    }
                },
                "service": {
                    "name": "unknown",
                    "version": "unknown",
                    "runtime": "node",
                    "runtime_version": "v14.19.0"
                },
                "origin": "AWS::ECS::Container",
                "subsegments": [
                    {
                        "id": "2a3c3b42a0b5051e",
                        "name": "S3",
                        "start_time": 1644932733.223,
                        "end_time": 1644932733.303,
                        "http": {
                            "response": {
                                "status": 200
                            }
                        },
                        "aws": {
                            "retries": 0,
                            "bucket_name": "raw-attachment-dev",
                            "region": "ap-southeast-2",
                            "operation": "PutObject",
                            "request_id": "xxxxx",
                            "key": "xxxxxx",
                            "id_2": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                            "resource_names": [
                                "xxxxxx"
                            ]
                        },
                        "namespace": "aws"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },  
        {
            "Id": "386f836607911d57",
            "Document": {
                "id": "386f836607911d57",
                "name": "S3",
                "start_time": 1644932733.223,
                "trace_id": "1-620bae7d-daf2e1177923ffb30e4c9729",
                "end_time": 1644932733.303,
                "parent_id": "2a3c3b42a0b5051e",
                "inferred": true,
                "http": {
                    "response": {
                        "status": 200
                    }
                },
                "aws": {
                    "retries": 0,
                    "bucket_name": "raw-attachment-dev",
                    "region": "ap-southeast-2",
                    "operation": "PutObject",
                    "request_id": "xxxxxx",
                    "key": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "id_2": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "resource_names": [
                        "xxxxxxxxxx"
                    ]
                },
                "origin": "AWS::S3::Bucket"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The second segment is autogenerated by AWS X-ray.
subsegment.id gives the value of "2a3c3b42a0b5051e", Which is not I am looking for.
I need to know the segment Id ("386f836607911d57") before sending the request to API.

Can you help me if you have any possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the s3 segment `386f836607911d57` is automatically inferred by xray and cannot be disabled.
May I know why you want to assign segment id for it?